# Visual Studio 2013 C# problems

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a copy of Visual Studio 2013, haven't used it much, but I'm getting all kinds of problems. I put together a new project that is supposed to be a Windows Forms Application.

All I need to do is to take data entered in TextBoxes and put it in another file. Does anybody have a link to tutorials on how to do that? I've been programming for 30 years, but Visual Studio C# is really completely counter intuitive.

My apologies to the folks at Microsoft- I'm sure they find it easy to use. But unless you totally immerse yourself in Visual Studio C# (which I don't care for, but it seemed like the quickest way to get data from TextBoxes) it is totally opaque.

Comment: What do you have so far? Have you created the textbox yet? (Drag and drop it from the toolbox to the designer.) If so, you might look at this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207492/visual-c-sharp-write-contents-of-a-textbox-to-a-txt-file

Comment: Yes, I have created the TextBox.

Comment: Okay, great. Drag and drop a button into the designer, then double-click it. This should take you to the event handler for the clicking of that button. Put code in that area similar to the following: File.WriteAllText(filename, textbox1.Text)

Comment: @LandscapePenguin it should be `File.AppendAllText(fileName, textbox1.Text);`. WriteAllText would overwrite the file, losing anything already placed inside of it.

Comment: @LandscapePenguin I know I've been over-engineering too long when my thinking on "simple" started with "Make a model class, write a routine to format it to desired format..."

Comment: Yes, I have a button, and I have double clicked on it. Yes, that added code. All I need to do is to add the contents of each of the text boxes (yes, there are several) to a file that is already existing. And all I asked for was directions to a tutorial. And my company does not use C#, we use C++. Let's keep the rudeness down.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to write the contents of a textbox to a file with the following code:

```
    using (var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\TestFile.txt", true))
    {
        file.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
    }
```

There are several examples of how to write to a text file here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a text file, it is a binary file.