# How to save an entry in a text box in Visual Studio | C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, savefiledialog

I understand it for a rich text box, inside an open file dialog control, for example,

```
richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName.RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
```

I understand it for using WriteLine, in the console, for example,

```
File.WriteAllText(path, variable)
```

But I am unsure how to use something other then a richTextBox to write a text file, for example a textbox, or a label. I tried using textBox1 in place of richTextBox1 but that does not seem correct.

Comment: What are you asking for? Are you asking how to get the text out of a text box? The actual question is very unclear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual C# - Write contents of a textbox to a .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207492/visual-c-sharp-write-contents-of-a-textbox-to-a-txt-file)

Answer (score 0):

```
File.WriteAllText(path, textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract the text out of the textbox first.

```
textbox1.Text //this gets you the text in the textbox
```

Comment: the Text property of a TextBox is defined as a string, no need to call ToString to convert a string to a string.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad Good catch